# WYSIWYG Editor missing on Stack Overflow

Tags: support

For the past couple of days, when I post a question, the WYSIWYG editor is missing and the live preview doesn't work either. Oddly, it's working here on the meta for me for some reason. I'm also getting hit with the CAPTCHA everytime I post questions. Anyone else having this problem?

Comment: Cleared your cache?

Comment: Yeah, but the problem keeps creeping back.

Comment: What browser? Can you check for script errors?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like your browser has some problems -- can you try a clean install of a different browser? Also, if on Firefox, disable all plugins and run in "safe mode".

Comment: Yeah, seems to be a Chrome issue. I've not been able to reproduce the error on any other browser.