# Preview and buttons does not appear on SO and SE, but work OK here on meta

Tags: support, bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WYSIWYG editor missing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132133/wysiwyg-editor-missing)

I don't know what's going on, but yesterday SO and some SE sites I read (Workplace, developers) have the preview broken and buttons disappeared. The strange thing is that it works here on MetaSO!?!?!?!

And main question: what I can do about it?

PS.:I cleared the FF cache thousands of times.